# how to create a panel in jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, jsfiddle

```
var layout = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
    //renderTo: 'layout',
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    //title: 'Border Layout', //no title will be blank
    layout: 'border',
    items: [{
            xtype: 'gmappanel',
            id : 'mygooglemap',
            gmapType: 'map',
            zoomLevel: 7,
            mapConfOpts: ['enableScrollWheelZoom','enableDoubleClickZoom','enableDragging'],
            mapControls: ['GSmallMapControl','GMapTypeControl','NonExistantControl'],  
            setCenter: {
                lat: 3.951941,
                lng: 102.052002,
            }
        }],
    renderTo: Ext.getBody() //get the body and display Layout at there
});
```

I have `renderto` Body but still can't display anything?

This the link to my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/anthor/Y4jP4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

baby steps Chin Ye, baby steps.

Modified your code to render the `panel`:
http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/tayua/

You selected extjs library in the fiddle and then included the library again through the resources link. Instead you need to include the css resource.

Comment: how to with gmappanel? @dbrin

Comment: I have never used it sir. You had other problems but at least you have a nice panel now and can take it from there. Fork my fiddle, the google apis are already loaded and the gmap.js is also sourced. Good luck!